# Milestone Reporting Format - Any ideas?

Tags: reporting

If I'm expecting the delivery of around 50 items from a contractor, each with their own forecast delivery dates and agreed need dates, what is the optimal way to track the forecast dates each time it's reported (in order to see any slippage/trends that give early warning signs)? Also, how would you best graphically represent this forecast when reporting up the chain?

Thanks for any assistance you can give!

Comment: What's wrong with a Gantt chart?

Comment: @CodeGnome I think the intent is a cumulative report (of history data), the Gantt chart (mostly) contains the baseline and the current data, so previous baselines would not be compared/visualized.

Answer (score 2):

My preference is to use a Milestone slip chart. 
[Example chart](http://www.gpmfirst.com/sites/default/files/book_uploads/9780566086038/files/graphics/fig10_3.jpg)

The horizontal axis is the forecast date, and the vertical axis is the reporting date. The advantage of these charts is that you can annotate them to summarise why Milestones have changed, so they can tell a story of the history of the project.

With the high number of Milestones you have, it would be better if you categorise them and only show 5 to 10 per chart.